# Why is $\epsilon_0$ a fixed point? Why don't/can't we define tetration of $\omega$ beyond $\omega$?

Tags: notation, set-theory, intuition, infinity, ordinals

I'm trying to learn about transfinite ordinals and got stuck here.

Once you've added $1$ infinitely, you can add another $1$ and get a larger result. If you take the successor of $$1+1+1+1+\dots = \omega,$$ the result is $(\omega+1)$, larger than $\omega$.

Once you've added a limit ordinal to itself infinite times, you can add it again and get a larger result. If you add $\omega$ to $\omega$ already added to itself infinitely $$\omega+\omega+\omega+\omega+\dots= \omega^2,$$ you get $\omega^2+\omega$, larger than $\omega^2$.

Once you've multiplied a limit ordinal by itself infinite times, the pattern holds. Multiply $\omega$ with itself infinitely $$\omega\cdot\omega\cdot\omega\cdot\omega\cdot\dots = \omega^\omega$$ and then multiply $\omega$ for $\omega^\omega\cdot\omega > \omega^\omega$.

But when exponentiating infinitely, it breaks. If you exponentiate $\omega$ to $\omega^{\omega^{\omega^{\omega^{\dots}}}}$, nothing changes and you get back $\omega^{\omega^{\omega^{\omega^{\dots}}}}$.

Why is that? Why isn't $\omega\uparrow\uparrow(\omega+1$ larger? How does one prove that $\omega\uparrow\uparrow(\omega+1)$ contains/is a subset of $\omega\uparrow\uparrow\omega
$?

Comment: I added correct formatting to your question (note that $\omega$ is not a W!). Here is a tutorial on using MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/7062. Please use MathJax to format your future questions.

Comment: following your logic, don't you want $\omega^{\omega^{\omega^{\omega^{\dots}}}}$ to $\omega$ rather than the opposite?

Comment: I guess it's because $(a^b)^c \approx a^{bc}$.

Comment: Note that you silently conflated $1+\alpha$ with $\alpha+1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at it this way:

- $1+\omega=\omega$ and $\omega$ is the least ordinal $\alpha$ with $1+\alpha=\alpha$.
- $\omega+\omega^2=\omega^2$ and $\omega^2$ is the least $\alpha$ with $\omega+\alpha=\alpha$.
- $\omega\cdot \omega^\omega=\omega^\omega$ and $\omega^\omega$ is the least $\alpha$ with $\omega\cdot\alpha=\alpha$.
- $\omega^{\varepsilon_0}=\varepsilon_0$ and $\varepsilon_0$ is the least $\alpha$ with $\omega^\alpha=\alpha$.

But $\omega+1>\omega$, $\omega^2+\omega>\omega^2$, $\omega^\omega\cdot\omega>\omega^\omega$ as you mention and similarly $\varepsilon_0^\omega>\varepsilon_0$. Your concern stems from treating the order of operations differently in the case of exponention towers compared to addition, multiplication etc.

Comment: +1.  I was thinking of posting exactly this answer but didn't have time to write it up :) .